# Myfaces Tomahawk: content inside panelTab

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, myfaces, tomahawk

I'm curious what is the right way to have the content (e.g. div) occupy 100% of t:panelTab inside of t:panelTabbedPane. It appears that the content gets rendered within div or span for which there's no way to specify style. The only way I was able to do that was using absolute layout. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try providing a custom CSS class using the `tabContentStyleClass` attribute for `<t:panelTabbedPane>`? Suppose you call it `ownStyleClass`, the pane gets rendered like

```
<tr class="myFaces_panelTabbedPane_contentRow">
    <td class="myFaces_panelTabbedPane_pane ownStyleClass" colspan="8">
```

which should allow for any custom layout.

Comment: The problem is that inside this <td> nested element is generated (div or span) for which there's no style